# KSH conventions scripting

Tags: scripting, ksh, conventions

I'm writing scripts in `ksh` atm. I'd like to know if there is any "conventions" as for example, always doing "unset" before using a variable, or using typeset to define a new variable, etc.

Answer (score 2):

If you use a variable in your script, I guess the first action on it would be to set its value to something which would make the unset useless.

If you use a variable without setting it first, your code is buggy unless it is a well known variable in which case you shouldn't unset it in the first place.

`typeset` has generally no added value unless you want to define a local variable in a ksh function, or if you want/need to give a type to your variable.

More generally, you'll certainly find various coding standard for shell scripting including ones specialized with ksh. What matters is being consistent, use a proper indentation, use variable and function names that help understanding your script but this is a general advice whatever the programming language.